# Angular 8 not updating globally to 9 on mac

Tags: angular, angular-cli, single-page-application, angular8, angular9

I am using a mac and I currently have version 8 of Angular installed.

I want to upgrade to Angular 9 so I've done this:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean or sudo npm cache verify
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

I go no errors but when I do

ng --version

It's return version 8.

How can I update to version 9?

Comment: do you get the same result if you run `cd / && ng --version`?

Comment: Yes I get Angular CLI: 8.0.2

Comment: did you try ng update @angular/cli  ?

Comment: That would not update globally

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you considered that you're uninstalling it by one name, installing by a second, and checking the version by a third? I don't quite understand how `ng` works, but it seems to be in `angular-cli/bin` in global installations. Maybe remove the `ng` file manually? https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/bin/ng

Comment: Cannot get rid of version 8. Now getting: Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating, when I try to update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to uninstall the existing angular cli packages followed by npm cache verify command to clear the cache related problems.

And the install the Angular CLI version again by using npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

Since you are on mac you can try it with sudo

```
sudo npm uninstall -g angular-cli
sudo npm cache clean or sudo npm cache verify (if npm > 5)
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Still says version 8.0.2

Answer (score 1):

Try this command to see if it work for you

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

npm install -g @angular/cli
```

or

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with your environment or NodeJS installation. Try to install [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Then `npm install @angular/cli -g`

Comment: Actually for me it was the other way around to solve this issue. I wanted to update globally from angular cli 8 to 10 and it never worked, alway stuck at version 8. Then I removed all node versions from nvm and deactived nvm, installed node.js the "normal" way and now it works.